# When will Skype 4.0 enter Ubuntu's repositories?

Tags: skype, repository

According to this [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/skype-40-for-linux-available-for.html), Skype 4.0 is released. So when will it enter Ubuntu's repo, and will `pidgin-skype` still be able to call back Skype for to chat?

Thanks for any further explanations!

Comment: This question should be addressed to the repo maintainers, not to the community.

Comment: Sorry for asking this, but where can I find them?

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/skype

Comment: I've just opened a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/skype/+bug/1013981

Comment: I tried this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype with Ubuntu 12.10 and the version installed is Skype 4.0 (most current today version is 4.1, but good enough). Too bad the question was closed.